# Azure Cosmos MongoDB "Throws Invalid BSON Field name" but it works in my local mongodb

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I'm exploring cosmos mongodb of Azure, I successfully created all the schema and seed data. But when I to run my test against the database it throws "Invalid BSON Field name 'Forms.$.Amt'" in Collections().UpdateOne() that should update the Amt field in Forms array that matches the id. This works in my local running on mongodb 3.2.8 and my app is using Mongodb C# driver 2.4.3

Here is my code:

```
    UpdateDefinition<FormEntity> updateDefinition = null;

    var filter = Builders<FormEntity>.Filter
        .Eq<ObjectId>(c => c.Id, id);
    filter = filter & Builders<FormEntity>.Filter
        .ElemMatch(c => c.Forms, c => c.Id.Equals(subFormId));

    //-- add to set if not existing.
    updateDefinition = Builders<FormEntity>
                .Update
                .Set("Forms.$.Amt", amount)
                .Set("Forms.$.AmtF", amountF)
                .Set(c => c.Audit.Updated, DateTime.Now);

    Collection().UpdateOne(filter, updateDefinition);
```

Schema :

```
    {
       {_id: 1},
       {Type: "Data"},
       Forms:
       [
         {_id:101, Amt:100.0, AmtF:5000.0}
       ],
       Audit: {Updated:...}
    }
```

I also tried the following all same error:

- Collection().FindAndUpdate
- .Set(c=> c.Forms[-1].Amount, amount)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Seems like CosmosDB doesn't support $ positional operator at this moment.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20091454-positional-array-update-via-query-support

You'll have to get the entire `Forms` array in the memory, find the element that you wanna update, change it in memory and then update the entire `Forms` array.